# How to get the local IP of the client in Netty Framework?

Tags: netty

I want to get the **remoteAddress** of the client from itself. I can already connect successfully to the server using:

```
b.connect(this.hostAddress.getHostAddress(), this.port).sync(); // b is a Bootstrap object
```

I am using `SimpleChannelInboundHandler` for the sake of simplicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the handler you would do `ctx.channel().remoteAddress()`. When using connect you can use `f.channel().remoteAddress()`

Comment: It's returning the `SocketAddress` of the server instead of the local socket of the client.